# Null error for nonempty data using Generate in Pig/Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am working on Task 2 in this link:
https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopbigdataoverview/certification-practice-exam

I used the code below

```
a = load '/user/horton/flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv' using PigStorage(',');
dump a
a_top = limit a 5
```

`a_top` shows that the first 5 rows. There are non-null values for each `Year`

Then I type

```
a_clean = filter a BY NOT ($4=='NA');
aa = foreach a_clean generate a_clean.Year;
```

But that gives the error

```
ERROR 1200: null
```

What is wrong with this?

EDIT: I also tried

```
a = load '/user/horton/flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (Year:chararray,Month:chararray,DayofMonth:chararray,DayOfWeek:chararray,DepTime:chararray,CRSDepTime:chararray,ArrTime:chararray,CRSArrTime:chararray,UniqueCarrier:chararray,FlightNum:chararray,TailNum:chararray,ActualElapsedTime:chararray,CRSElapsedTime:chararray,AirTime:chararray,ArrDelay:chararray,DepDelay:chararray,Origin:chararray,Dest:chararray,Distance:chararray,TaxiIn:chararray,TaxiOut:chararray,Cancelled:chararray,CancellationCode:chararray,Diverted:chararray,CarrierDelay:chararray,WeatherDelay:chararray,NASDelay:chararray,SecurityDelay:chararray,LateAircraftDelay:chararray);
```

and

```
aa = foreach a_clean generate a_clean.Year
```

but the error was

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,CRSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay), 2nd :(2008,1,3,4,2003,1955,2211,2225,WN,335,N712SW,128,150,116,-14,8,IAD,TPA,810,4,8,0,,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified the schema in the LOAD statement,you will have to refer the columns using order in which they occur.Year seems to be the first column so try this

```
a_clean = filter a BY ($4 != 'NA');
aa = foreach a_clean generate a.Year;
```

Comment: if I try that I get the error `ERROR 2271 Logical plan invalid state: invalid uid -1 in schema: #-1:bytearray`

Comment: I tried to specify the schema in the LOAD statement but still got errors. See the EDIT in my OP

Comment: @user6347191 I've updated the answer.You need a :: instead of .

Comment: If I use `::` I then get the error `Projected field [a_clean::Year] does not exist in schema: Year:chararray,Month:chararray ..`

Comment: @user6347191 try this aa = foreach a_clean generate a::Year; if that doesn't work then use the dot operator aa = foreach a_clean generate a.Year;